# Handling result of start_link/3 when using Supervisor

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

I have a supervisor set up to supervise a [Slack](https://hexdocs.pm/slack/Slack.html) websocket:

```
children = [
  %{
    id: Slack.Bot,
    start: {Slack.Bot, :start_link, [MyBot, [], "api_token"]}
  }
]
opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyBot.Supervisor]
Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
```

`MyBot` receives various callbacks when messages arive via the websocket. This is fine, but there is an additional callback, [`handle_info/3`](https://github.com/BlakeWilliams/Elixir-Slack/blob/master/lib/slack/bot.ex#L104), that I want to use to handle my own events. In order to do this I need to send a message to the process myself.

I see I can get the PID from the result of `start_link/3`, but this is called automatically by the Supervisor. How can I get the PID of this process in order to send it a message, while still keeping it supervised? Do I have to implement and extra supervision layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Supervisors, pids and start functions

Supervisors expect start functions to return one of these three values:

```
{:ok, pid}
{:ok, pid, any}
{:error, any}
```

In your code, the start function is [`Slack.Bot.start_link/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/slack/Slack.Bot.html#start_link/4) with last arguments being the empty list by default.

You notice you cannot access the pid because the results of the start functions are lost through the usage of Elixir's [`Supervisor.start_link/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#start_link/2). In some cases, it makes sense to invoke [`Supervisor.start_child/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#start_child/2) instead, which returns the pid of the started child (and additional info, if any). And for completeness, the pids of supervised processes can also be queried with [`Supervisor.which_children/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#which_children/1).

However, supervisors' role is to supervise processes and restart them when necessary. When a process is restarted, it gets a new pid. For this reason, the pid is not the proper way to refer to a process for a long duration.

## Pids and names

The solution to your problem is to refer to the process by **name**. The virtual machine maintains a mapping of names of processes (as well as ports) and allows to refer to processes (and ports) by name instead of pids (and port references). The primitive to register a process is [`Process.register/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#register/2). Most functions, if not all, that expect a pid also accept a registered name. Names are unique within a node.

While `spawn*` primitives do not register processes by names, code built on top of them often provides the ability to register names through the start procedure. This is the case of `Slack.Bot.start_link/4` as well as `Supervisor.start_link/2`. Typically, this is what your code does by passing a `:name` option to `Supervisor.start_link/2`. BTW, this is useless unless you need to refer to the Supervisor process later on, which is probably not the case as hinted by several bits of your code.

## The case of `Slack.Bot.start_link/4`

To be able to refer to your bot process, simply make sure that `Slack.Bot.start_link/4` is invoked with a `:name` option with a name of your choice (an atom), for example `MyBot`. This is done within the child specification.

```
children = [
  %{
    id: Slack.Bot,
    start: {Slack.Bot, :start_link, [MyBot, [], "api_token", %{name: MyBot}]}
  }
]
opts = [strategy: :one_for_one]
Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
```

As a result, the supervisor will invoke `Slack.Bot.start_link/4` function with the four provided arguments (`[MyBot, [], "api_token", [name: MyBot]`) and `Slack.Bot.start_link/4` will register the process with the provided name.

If you choose `MyBot` as a name as above, you can send it a message with:

```
Process.send(MyBot, :message_to_bot, [])
```

or by using [`Kernel.send/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#send/2) primitive:

```
send(MyBot, :message_to_bot)
```

It will then be processed by `handle_info/3` callback.

As a side note, processes in OTP supervision trees with a registered name probably should be based on OTP modules and let OTP framework do the registration. In OTP framework, name registration happens very early in the init phase and if there is a conflict, the process is stopped and `start_link` returns an error (`{:error,{:already_started,pid}}`).

`Slack.Bot.start_link/4` is indeed based on OTP modules: it is based on `:websocket_client` module which is itself based on `:gen_fsm` from OTP. However, in its [current implementation](https://github.com/BlakeWilliams/Elixir-Slack/blob/master/lib/slack/bot.ex#L44), instead of passing the name down to `:websocket_client.start_link/4` which passes it down to `:gen_fsm.start_link/4`, the function registers the name directly with `Process.register/2`. As a result, if there is a name conflict, the bot might connect to Slack anyway.

## Asynchronous messages and replies

`Process.send/3` as well as `Kernel.send/2` primitive send a message asynchronously. These functions return immediatly.

If the first parameter is the pid of the process, these functions succeed even if the process is no longer running. If it is an atom, they will fail if no process is registered by this name.

To get a reply from the bot process, you need to implement some mechanism where the bot process knows where to send the reply to. This mechanism is provided by OTP's gen_server and its Elixir counterpart [`GenServer.call/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#call/3), yet this is not available here as part of Slack.Bot API.

The Erlang way to do this is to send a tuple with the pid of the caller, typically as the first argument. So you would do:

```
send(MyBot, {self(), :message_to_bot})
receive do result -> result end
```

The bot then receives and replies to the message as:

```
def handle_info({caller, message}, slack, state) do
    ...
    send(caller, result)
end
```

This is a very simplistic version of the call. `GenServer.call/2` does more such as handling timeout, making sure the response is not some random message you would get but the result of the call, and that the process does not disappear during the call. In this simple version, your code could wait forever for the reply.

To prevent this, you should at least add a timeout and a way to make sure this is not a random message such as:

```
def call_bot(message) do
    ref = make_ref()
    send(MyBot, {self(), ref, message})
    receive do
        {:reply, ^ref, result} -> {:ok, result}
    after 5_000 ->
        {:error, :timeout}
    end
end
```

And for the handle_info part, simply return the opaque ref that was passed in the tuple:

```
def handle_info({caller, ref, message}, slack, state) do
    ...
    send(caller, {:reply, ref, result})
end
```

[`make_ref/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#make_ref/0) is a primitive creating a new, unique ref, typically for this usage.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I didn't realise when I asked the question, but instead of just sending a message, I want to also retrieve the response in a similar way to `GenServer.call`. In this case I have to also add a `Process.send` call in `MyBot` to send the reply (or else make `MyBot` a `GenServer`), right?

Comment: I think the `options` needs to be a map, so the `start:` line should be `start: {Slack.Bot, :start_link, [MyBot, [], "api_token", %{name: MyBot}]}`

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Indeed, you need to send a reply with send/2 or Process.send/3, I added a section about this. And I believe you are correct with options being a map, I fixed the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I forgot about `Kernel.send` and didn't know about `make_ref`. In this case I am fetching a value for a given key, so I think I can use the key instead of make_ref here, but I understand its usefulness (I suppose using the key will mean the replies to multiple requests for the same key are indistinguishable, but I don't think that matters for this application).

Answer (score 3):

You don’t necessarily need a PID. Elixir allows to use *named* processes and [`Process.send/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#send/3) perfectly accepts *names* as a first argument. Given you named your bot `MyBot.Supervisor` as in your example, the following would successfully send a message to it:

```rb
Process.send(MyBot.Supervisor, :message_to_bot, [:noconnect])
```

or, if your bot is running on different node:

```rb
Process.send({MyBot.Supervisor, :node_name}, :message_to_bot, [:noconnect])
```

In general, using the name not the PID is the common practice in Elixir for everything related to sending messages, since PIDs are subjects to change when the process crashes/restarts, while the name is preserved forever.

Comment: I see, calling the process by name looks useful. The purpose of sending the message is to look up some data. How would I do something like GenServer.call to retrieve the result in this case?

Comment: Just put a name wherever you wanted to put a PID. They are fully interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a GenServer to store the PID and then you can reference that as needed. The flow would be something like this: Make a `MyServer` genserver that holds on to your slackbot PID. Then, inside the GenServer, you can do something like `send(state.slack, :display_leaderboard)` inside a call or cast handler.

```
defmodule MyServer do
  use GenServer

  def child_spec(team_id) do
    %{
      id: __MODULE__,
      start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, [team_id]},
      type: :worker
    }
  end

  def start_link(team_id) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, team_id)
  end

  def init(team_id) do
    {:ok, pid} = Slack.Bot.start_link(MyBot, [], team_id)
    {:ok, %{slack: pid}}
  end
```

Comment: You can see a working example here: https://github.com/ellevargas/snapeth-worker/blob/master/lib/snapeth.ex and some related code about multiple slack workers here https://github.com/AnilRedshift/yatlab-worker/blob/master/lib/team_monitor.ex

Comment: _“You should use a `GenServer`“_ —“should” is too much wording here. In general, one might never bother about PIDs in Elixir using names instead.

Comment: What happens when your Slack.Bot process crashes? In this example, the process is not supervised and will nit be restarted if it crashes. Naming your process, as suggested @mudasobwa s answer allows you to supervise the process and find it by it's name.

Comment: @nico unnamed processes might be perfectly supervised as well. You just need to handle PID changed manually.

Comment: @mudasobwa, that's interesting, would you please share how you can supervise a process that has already been started?

Comment: @nico I am lost. Of course one cannot “start supervising” an already running process, despite whether it’s named or not.

Comment: @mudasobwa Right, that is what I thought. My original comment was not saying that unnamed processes cannot be supervised, what I meant was that the Slack.Bot process in this code example, is not being supervised, and I would not recommend using it in this way.